# Subset Relation is What Kind of Relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to determine whether the $\subseteq$ relation is reflexive, symmetric, transitive and serial.

I'm slightly confused as to how to begin

I know that $A\subseteq B$  iff $\forall x (x\in A \rightarrow x\in B).$

And I have quantified definitions of reflexivity, symmetry, seriality, transitivity:

R is reflexive iff $\forall x Rxx$.
R is symmetrical iff $\forall x,y  (Rxy \rightarrow Ryx)$.
R is transitive iff $\forall x,y,z (Rxy \land Ryz \rightarrow Rxz)$.
R is serial iff $\forall x \exists y Rxy.$

I understand these in the abstract. But I'm confused about how knowing the definitions of the relevant kinds of relations and the definition of $
\subseteq$ can help me determine whether $\subseteq$ is reflexive, symmetrical, transitive and/or serial.

Does anyone have any advice about how to proceed? (I've read through a similar question posted from 3 years ago but it does not help me understand how to go about doing this problem).

Comment: Apply the def... $A \subseteq A$ iff $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in A)$.

Comment: This sound good... thus: $\forall x (A \subseteq A)$ and the $\subseteq$ rel is reflexive.

Comment: And so on......

Comment: You have to consider that the expression $x \subseteq y$ has the same "form" of $xRy$. It is a binary relation between sets.

Comment: Symmtery: in general no. If $A \subseteq B$, not necessarily we have also $B \subseteq A$ (otherwise $A=B$).

Answer (score 1):

Reflexive: Is it true for all sets $A$ that $A\subseteq A$?

Symmetric: Is it always true that if $A\subseteq B$, then $B\subseteq A$?

Transitive:  Is it always true that if $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$, then $A\subseteq C$?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating your definitions, you have:

- $\subseteq$ is reflexive if $\forall A,\ A \subseteq A$
- $\subseteq$ is symmetric if $\forall A,B,\ A \subseteq B \Rightarrow B \subseteq A$
- $\subseteq$ is transitive if $\forall A,B,C,\ (A \subseteq B \wedge B \subseteq C) \Rightarrow A \subseteq C$
- $\subseteq$ is serial if $\forall A,\, \exists B,\, B \subseteq A$

You should use the given definition of $\subseteq$ to check which of these conditions hold and which do not.

I'll get you started with a proof that $\subseteq$ is reflexive. Let $A$ be a set. We need to prove $A \subseteq A$. For all $x$, the statement $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in A$ is certainly true, and hence $A \subseteq A$ is true. So $\subseteq$ is reflexive.